# Append rows in the table one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append rows to the table one by one, not all at once. Problem i'm facing is, no. of rows is very large, say 10,000. It append all the rows at once after loop terminates. I want it to work like, with each iteration, it should append the row to the table.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
    var name = "name "+i;
    var email = "email"+i+"@vvv.com";
    var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td></tr>";
    //$("table tbody").append(markup);
    //$("tbody").parent("table").append(markup);
    $("tbody").after(markup);
  }
});
```

```css
   table{
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table, th, td{
        border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    }
    table th, table td{
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="record"></td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>email@vvv.com</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You need `.append()` i.e. `$("tbody").append(markup);`, Whats the objective of using `after()`?

Comment: Do you mean so a person can see it adding rows or just like you have in now?

Comment: 10K rows is a bad idea to add one at a time. If you want it to be one at a time, than you can not use a for loop.

Comment: If you want to have it added and having the people see it added row by row you'd have to get your code to run async and have a little delay (I think at least) because it is sync now so it appends everything and then shows it, because the browser is still busy appending stuff so it doesn't react and render (show). But I agree with @epascarello, you should load in batches and use different pages. Take a look at http://datatables.net (I recommend it if you want 10000K rows)

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying to do. You may try to use setTimeout to achieve this. You are trying to loop an array but in your code you are just generating new rows. So I tried to implement your code into this solution. If you are trying to loop an array you need to modify this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 appendOneByOne(1000)
});

function appendOneByOne(i){
  if(i !== 0){
    setTimeout(function(){
      var name = "name "+i;
      var email = "email"+i+"@vvv.com";
      var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td></tr>";
      $("tbody").after(markup);
      appendOneByOne(--i)
    });
  }
}
```

You can also use `window.requestAnimationFrame();` but take care for cross-browser issues.

Comment: Yeah that'd only take nearly three HOURS to display.

Comment: @j08691 I bet, it won't take more than 15ms when we compare to for loop.

Comment: 10,000 rows at one per second. Do the math.

Comment: setTimeout(function(){}, 0) ==  setTimeout(function(){});

Comment: 10K rows took me over 9 minutes on a decent PC. On older machines it would take hours :-)

Comment: @AhmetCanGüven it is taking time to load rows in the table but those rows are appending later so no issues.

Comment: @RohitBisht Nice to hear it helped you :)